C# SELECT INTO SQL File
I have an SQL file that looks like this:
DECLARE
    ID_CB VARCHAR2(15) := '{ID_CB}';

BEGIN
SELECT * FROM DEMANDES WHERE ID_CB = ID_CB;
END;

I read this file in C# and then use the Replace command to replace the value of the variable with the actual value:
var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
var sqlSkript = content;
sqlSkript = sqlSkript.Replace($"{{{param.Key}}}", param.Value);

This also works so far. Then I try to execute the SQL statement and load it into a DataTable.
using (var command = new OracleCommand(sqlSkript) { Connection = oracleConnection })
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    return dataTable;
  }
}

but then I get the following error:
PLS-00428: An INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Previously I had a simple SELECT in the SQL file without first defining a variable via DECLARE and I had no problems executing the SELECT. Why do I now need an Into command?
I have tried to include the INTO in my file. Since I have very little experience in SQL, I do not know exactly what is happening, but I have read the %ROWTYPE on the Internet. I have freely assigned the name demande_row.
DECLARE
    ID_CB VARCHAR2(15) := '{ID_CB}';
    demande_row DEMANDES%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
SELECT * INTO demande_row FROM DEMANDES WHERE ID_CB = ID_CB;
END;

but then I get the following error:
ORA-01422: Exact retrieval returns more than the requested number of lines


WHERE ID_CB = ID_CB - what's that expected to mean? I'd guess WHERE ID_CB is not null. Am I right or wrong? As intended?

Tip: Don't name your variable the same as any column. For example, you could choose V_ID_CB.

Are you expecting a single row or multiple rows - i.e. is your ID unique? Either way you need to get the result in a form your client can see it, not something local to the PL/.SQL block. But why did you decide to change from plain SQL to PL/SQL? You could do your substitution directly in the SQL instead (maybe you were before, and were told not to?), but it would be better to use a plain SQL query with bind variables.

@jarlh No, I am comparing the ID_CB column with the value of the ID_CB variable that I defined in the SQL file above using DECLARE. Yes, you are right, I have changed the name of my variable, but I still get the message ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

@AlexPoole I expect multiple rows. The content of this SQL file will be expanded. The SQL file you see here was just so that I know why I get this message ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. I can't use plain SQL because I have to define variables within the SQL file beforehand. The idea behind this is that I can only specify parameters in the C# application and all the logic as to when which SQL query is executed then takes place within the SQL file.

Why don't you use a parametrized query like select * from DEMANDES where ID_CB = :prm_ID_CB, set bind variable and execute it?

"The content of this SQL file will be expanded" - that suggests you will either have multiple statements in this script, which i don't think will work with OracleCommand - pretty sure that expects a single statement; or you will have it all wrapped in a PL/SQL block, which will make it difficult to get results out.

Perhaps it would be better to call a stored procedure that returns a ref cursor. That would be following a pattern that C# handles. You can have any logic you want in the procedure.

Don't name your PL/SQL variables with the same name as the column. The SQL engine will take the variable from the local (SQL) scope over the outer (PL/SQL) scope so you are effectively doing:
DECLARE
  ID_CB VARCHAR2(15) := '{ID_CB}';
  demande_row DEMANDES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   demande_row
  FROM   DEMANDES d
  WHERE  d.ID_CB = d.ID_CB;
END;

So you are comparing the column value to itself (and not to the PL/SQL variable that is shadowed by the column).
What you want is:
DECLARE
  v_id_cb VARCHAR2(15) := '{ID_CB}';
  demande_row DEMANDES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   demande_row
  FROM   DEMANDES
  WHERE  ID_CB = v_id_cb;
END;

However, it would be MUCH better if you used bind variables:
DECLARE
  demande_row DEMANDES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   demande_row
  FROM   DEMANDES
  WHERE  ID_CB = :v_id_cb;
END;

and (untested):
using (var command = new OracleCommand(sqlSkript) { Connection = oracleConnection })
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":v_id_cb", param.Value);
  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    return dataTable;
  }
}

Then your code will not be as vulnerable to SQL injection attacks and you can pass the variable from C# rather than using replace.
However, you probably don't need PL/SQL (because the PL/SQL is going to select the value into a row variable and then do nothing with it). Instead, you could simply use an SQL query:
SELECT *
FROM   DEMANDES
WHERE  ID_CB = :v_id_cb;


Thanks for the hint, I have changed the name of my variable so that it no longer matches the name of the column. I cannot use bind variables because the SQL file must have its own variables declared. Accordingly, I also need PL/SQL. The idea behind this is that users can create their own SQL in my C# application, even if they are not familiar with it. The whole logic should be done in this SQL file and therefore my task is only to initialize the variables by replace.

I tried your suggestion where you gave the variable a different name than the column name. I still get the error ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

@Akin "Accordingly, I also need PL/SQL." I do not see how you reach that conclusion. If you must use find-replace (I still think it is an SQL injection vulnerability) then SELECT * FROM DEMANDES WHERE ID_CB = {ID_CB}; is probably what you want.

@Akin If you are getting ORA-01422 then either: BULK COLLECT INTO a collection variable; open a cursor; or don't use PL/SQL and use an SQL statement instead.
